# Analysis of BJT transistor circuit

Tags: transistors, bjt

in the image, 2 loops are formed, is it possible to form a loop for the last one? If so, what equation would arise?

[image]

Comment: What equation do you think would arise?

Comment: 16 - Vc - Vbe - Vbc = 0?

Comment: You don't have any term for your resistor, and the base doesn't need to come into it at all.

Comment: for resistor is 1*Ic, why doesnt base need to come in?

Comment: What is so hard about analyzing [your schematic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/s2Lr9.png)?

Comment: You are confused.  Neither of \$V_C\$,  \$V_{BE}\$ or \$V_{BC}\$ are correct and like Felthry said, you have left out 1kΩ resistor.

Answer (score 0):

The symbols for your batteries are upside down. The long bar should be positive and the short bar should be negative.

The collector current in a transistor that is not saturated is Ib/hFE. Your schematic has the base voltage number cut off the image so we cannot calculate the base current.